# the method of substitution.

Tags: integration

Show that if $x>0$
$$\int_{x}^{1} \frac{dt}{1+t^2} = \int_{1}^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$
my progress:
I try with this $$ \int_{c}^{x} f(g(t))g'(t)dt = \int_{g(c)}^{g(x)} f(u)du$$
I consider $g(t)= \frac{t}{x}$ and $\int_{x}^{1} \frac{1}{1+(\frac{t}{x})^2} \frac{dt}{x}=\int_{1}^{\frac{1}{x}} \frac{dt}{1+t^2}$ then want $$ 0 =\int_{x}^{1} \frac{dt}{1+t^2}-\int_{x}^{1} \frac{1}{1+(\frac{t}{x})^2} \frac{dt}{x}=\int_{x}^{1} \frac{1}{1+t^2}-\frac{1}{(1+(\frac{t}{x})^2)x} dt$$
and so. some hint for solve this in other correctly form. I know I don't solve it. And this is an exercise form Calculus 1 TM Apostol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is also another way which works with your formula

$$\int_1^x {{1 \over {1 + {t^2}}}dt}  = \int_1^x {{{{t^2}} \over {1 + {t^2}}}{1 \over {{t^2}}}dt}  = \int_1^x {{1 \over {1 + {{\left( {{1 \over t}} \right)}^2}}}{1 \over {{t^2}}}dt} $$

Now choose $f(x) = {1 \over {1 + x}}$ and $g(t) = {1 \over t}$. Then it follows that

$$\int_1^x {{1 \over {1 + {{\left( {{1 \over t}} \right)}^2}}}{1 \over {{t^2}}}dt}  =  - \int_1^x {f(g(t))g'(t)dt}  =  - \int_{g(1)}^{g(x)} {f(u)du}  =  - \int_1^{{1 \over x}} {{1 \over {1 + {u^2}}}du}  = \int_{{1 \over x}}^1 {{1 \over {1 + {t^2}}}dt} $$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Start with $I = \int_x^1 \frac{dt}{1 + t^2}$. Substitute $u = 1/t$. Then $du = -1/t^2 \, dt$ or $dt = (-1/u^2)\, du$ and

$$I = \int_{1/u}^1\frac{1}{1 + 1/u^2} \cdot\frac{-1}{u^2} du$$
Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 0):

Try the substitution

$$t = {1 \over u}$$

then it follows that

$$\eqalign{
  & t = x\,\,\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,\,\,\,u = {1 \over x}  \cr 
  & t = 1\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\,\,\,\,u = 1 \cr} $$

and consider that

$$\eqalign{
  & dt =  - {1 \over {{u^2}}}du  \cr 
  & {1 \over {1 + {t^2}}} = {1 \over {1 + {1 \over {{u^2}}}}} = {{{u^2}} \over {1 + {u^2}}} \cr} $$

using the above relations you can conclude

$$\int_1^x {{1 \over {1 + {t^2}}}dt}  = \int_{{1 \over x}}^1 {{{{u^2}} \over {1 + {u^2}}} \times  - {1 \over {{u^2}}}du}  =  - \int_{{1 \over x}}^1 {{1 \over {1 + {u^2}}}du}  = \int_1^{{1 \over x}} {{1 \over {1 + {u^2}}}du}  = \int_1^{{1 \over x}} {{1 \over {1 + {t^2}}}dt} $$

The whole thing is equivalent to choosing